# Is bundle's tip transaction always the tail transaction

Tags: bundles

So I read it [here](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/910/1015) that:

> only the first transaction (the "tail transaction") appears as a tip

So is the tip transaction of a bundle always the tail transaction?
And it is also the "first transaction" with index 0?

It is kinda confusing because the word "tail" seems to be the opposite of the word "first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the transaction that *appears as a tip* is the always the tail transaction of a bundle.
And yes, the transaction **0** in a bundle is always its **tail transaction**.

References:

- [iota.lib.js `isBundle()` Documentation](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/141df389a9ead2e83fbc2cf913cbff6818347618/README.md#isbundle)

  > The provided bundle has to be ordered tail (i.e. currentIndex: 0) first.
- https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/910/10

  > Therefore, only the first transaction (the "tail transaction") appears as a tip (the others are not tips as they have already one transaction that approves them)